# Play count for mp3 share link by orangebox

Tags: orangedox

I generate a shared link of an mp3 file. When I click on the link, it starts the download immediately. Can I stream/play the file in the browser and get the play count statistics instead?

Comment: FYI it seems that clicking the download link on a mobile device causes the files to stream - and that seems to be counted in the "download count."

Answer (score 1):

Sharing mp3 and other audio and video files with Orangedox only allows for downloading and not steaming/playing within the browser at this time.